# Objective-C Blocks Not Being Called after Cocoapods Update

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, cocoapods

I have a call to a block - specifically, it's a block for UIAlertView that provides functionality based on what button is pressed. I'm using UIAlertView+Blocks, which can be found here: https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIAlertView-Blocks

Everything was peachy keen until I recently refreshed Cocoapods via the 'pod install' command. Despite the version of UIAlertView+Blocks not changing, the simply act of updating my cocoapods wrapper workspace has caused the very weird error of no longer calling any completion blocks for UIAlertView+Blocks.

Thinking it might be an error in the pod, I tried two other cocoapods for UIAlertView completion blocks. No dice - any completion block for the UIAlertView is being skipped.

A method in question:

```
[UIAlertView showWithTitle:@"Change Password" 
  message:@"Please enter your new password below." 
  style:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput 
  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
  otherButtonTitles:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"OK", nil] 
  tapBlock:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {

    //THIS PART ISN'T BEING CALLED
    NSLog(@"Change password, do some other stuff...");

    //Do other things...

}];
```

All other blocks for other classes are working fine. It's just blocks related to UIAlertView that have stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions/questions.

1. Clean your project and also the derived data, build again.
2. Have you changed the device/simulator iOS version that you are running this on? UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS8 - iOS8 uses [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html) as the alert class for UIAlertView and UIActionSheet. The pod you use was last updated 7 months ago and is written for UIAlertView not the UIAlertController.

Comment: Cleaned and deleted derived data - no luck.  I also tried this under both iOS 7 and 8 simulators - again no luck. Interestingly, it works fine under both simulators in the example project included on github. It's specific to my project.

Comment: Have you tried removing pods completely and re-installing it? Sometimes project settings can get messed up when redoing install.

Are you tracking changes to your project in a git repo? If you do then make a diff of the project and workspace files before and after you did pod install. Even better, try to revert those changes to an earlier version. Looks like something in the project configuration got messed up.

Comment: Turns out it was related to the project configuration and a bad interaction between two cocoapods. In the end, I had to choose which of the two to keep, and I pulled out the UIAlertView+Blocks cocoapod and used an alternative - UIBAlertView, which did not have the same conflict.  I don't think it makes sense to checkmark your answer, but I upvoted your comment, which proved to be the key piece of info I needed!

Comment: Well you figured it out yourself so that's fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

[Kaupo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1129733/kaupo) provided the key piece of information - I checked my git diff and found that one of my other cocoapods was also being updated, and the two together were causing a conflict on the UIAlertView delegate system - that's why the block wasn't being called. /facepalm

In the end, I solved the problem by using a different cocoapod for my UIAlertViews - [UIBAlertView](https://github.com/stavash/UIBAlertView)